# Recursive Symbolic links

Tags: symlink

I want to drop through my mp3 folders and create a sym link to each mp3 in a folder called links. I would like for my links to be relative to the directory structure rather than absolute. I tried this and no luck.

```
find . -name "*.mp3" -type l -delete; mp3="mp3"; for i in ./*/; do; ln -s  ../links/ "$i$mp3"; done
```

Can someone help please?

Comment: Looks like the * was omitted in my cmd line. should be. find . -name "*.mp3" -type l -delete; mp3="mp3"; for i in ./*/; do; ln -s  ../links/ "$i$mp3"; done

Comment: Please try a ***lot*** harder to explain this clearly.  You talk about creating, but you show a command that does deletes. Huh? Why?  What do you mean by “recursive”?  It would help if you showed an example before and after. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `links` is on the same level as your mp3 directory structure or above (or else you have to adjust the relative path `..`):

```
cd /path/to/links
find .. -name "*.mp3" -type f -exec ln -s {} \;
```

Note that the mp3 files can have the same filenames and the first one found "wins" the symbolic link.